# Plotting certain time points in a parametric equation?

Tags: plotting, graphics, parametric-functions

I'm using *Mathematica* 5.0 and I have the following problem.
I have the following parametric equation that I plotted successfully.

```
x = Sin[(Pi/3)*t]*(Exp[Cos[(Pi/2)*t]] - Sin[Pi*t] + (Sin[(Pi/3)*t/12])^5);
y = Cos[(Pi/3)*t]*(Exp[Sin[(Pi/2)*t]] - Cos[Pi*t] + (Sin[(Pi/3)*t/12])^5);
```

Where `t∈[a, b]` and `a` and `b` are entered manually by the user.
I'm now required to plot the points where `t = a, a+1, a+2, ..., b`. I made a table of all these values with

```
fd = Table[t == w, {w, a, b, 1}]
```

But now I'm stuck trying to figure out how to calculate the $x$ and $y$ coordinates for these points using `ListPlot` to plot them.

Please, simple basic instructions only, as I'm VERY new to this (if you haven't already noticed)!

Comment: Using your definitions of `x` and `y`, consider `ListPlot[Table[{x, y}, {t, a, b, 1}], PlotRange -> All]`. Beware that `a` and `b` must have been assigned values already before you execute this expression.

Answer (score 1):

I think MarcoB suggestion, made in a comment, should be put on record.

```
x = Sin[(π t)/3] (Exp[Cos[(π t)/2]] - Sin[π t] + Sin[(π t)/(3 12)]^5);
y = Cos[(π t)/3] (Exp[Sin[(π t)/2]] - Cos[π t] + Sin[(π t)/(3 12)]^5);

With[{a = 0, b = 30 π}, ListPlot[Table[{x, y}, {t, a, b, .02}]]]
```

[image: plot]